# v-autocomplete doesn't trigger search-input.sync when you change the name of function

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm playing with Vuetify and autocomplete component. In the official [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes#examples), with the first [example](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101) in codepen, when I've changed the name of the event (and function) to bound, it doesn't work. The code:

```
:search-input.sync="search"
```

to
    :search-input.sync="renamedSearch"

and the function too

```
  watch: {
   search (val) { // changed to:
   renamedSearch(val) {
```

I've seen it when I've tried to use two autocompletes and the second search never worked.

How can I use another autocomplete or change the name of the function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add your new value in data

`data() { return{ renamedSearch:'', }}`